# swift: can I have a property thats actually a reference?

Tags: ios, swift, reference

for example.. I want to pass in some dictionaries into a class in its initializer, and i want to reference those dictionaries across my class.. the problem is when I set them as properties, they are actually being copied, not referenced.

example:

```
var activeDict: [Int: Projectile]
var inactiveDict: [Int: Projectile]

init(inout activeDict: [Int: Projectile], inout inactiveDict: [Int: Projectile]) {
    self.activeDict = activeDict
    self.inactiveDict = inactiveDict
```

I want to use `activeDict`, and `inactiveDict` across my class.  I want them to be references of the originals that are being passed in.

Comment: Use NSDictionaries, not Swift dictionaries

Comment: can you provide an example

Comment: var `activeDict: NSDictionary` - as you will then be using an object it will be passed by reference

Comment: I'm having some issues because I can't change the values of an NSDictionary (obviously).. if I cast to NSMutableDictionary then I get "NSDictionary is not a subtype of NSMutableDictionary"

Comment: Sorry, you need NSMutableDictionary

Comment: i'm having issues with that, read above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69374/discussion-between-paulw11-and-hamobi).

Comment: I updated my answer, so now it fits your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can store an UnsafeMutablePointer to the dictionary, here is an example, tested in playground:

```
var dict = ["hejj": 1]

class A<T> {
    var myDictRef: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>

    init(ref: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>) {
        self.myDictRef = ref
    }
}

let a = A(ref: &dict)
a.myDictRef.memory["asd"] = 3
a.myDictRef.memory
dict
```

**Updated**

In your case use it like that:

```
var activeDict: UnsafeMutablePointer<[Int: Projectile]>
var inactiveDict: UnsafeMutablePointer<[Int: Projectile]>

init(activeDict: UnsafeMutablePointer<[Int: Projectile]>, inactiveDict: UnsafeMutablePointer<[Int: Projectile]>) {
    self.activeDict = activeDict
    self.inactiveDict = inactiveDict
}
```

whenever you want to use activeDict or inactiveDict, you can call the dictionary behind the pointer with their memory property like:

```
activeDict.memory[YourKey] = YourValue
```